# Timeout trying to connect to a database via LinqPad5

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

I've just created a new SQL Server 2014 database on my hosted server, and can connect fine to it using SQL Server Management Studio.

If I try connect via LinqPad, and enter my details, click the "*Display all in a TreeView*" then the Test button is enabled, and if I click it, it tells me the connection was successful.

However, when I try to open the dropdown next to "*Specify new or existing database*", I get a message "*Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding*"

Anyone any ideas? I've obviously entered the right connection info, it just won't populate the dropdown. I've successfully connected to other database on this shared hosting before, so it's not that.

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Anyone? I really need to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, it turned out that the hosting company didn't allow users to run the `dbo.sp_MShasdbaccess` stored procedure. LinqPad uses this to populate the dropdown.

The answer was to ignore the dropdown and add the database name manually. This worked fine.